# Change URL structure in the CI

Tags: codeigniter, url

I was asked to change structure in the CI, it like this:

In each controller, each with its own directory , each directory has the file controller.
- Normally, each time when running, we call to directory that contains the file Controller, then calling Class controller and Method, ... 
- And now just call an alias , it is self-understanding is pointing to any directory, any class . (Each alias will replace a directory, a class)

**Example:** Suppose there **Listtype folder** (directory Controller), *including file Category (category.php).*

=> call in the normal way :

> localhost/demo/index.php/listtype/category/method/

And just call “alias”

> localhost/demo/index.php/alias/method/

In it, “alias” will replace **listtype / category**. I have used in the configuration file (route.php) but not correct

> $route[‘alias/(:num)’] = “listtype/category/$1”;

But I think it doesn’t work all cases (as if there are more variables in each segment, ...)
Please help me solve this problem, thanks very much

Sorry my English.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to send method to codeigniter route config.

```
$route[‘alias/(:any)’] = “listtype/category/$1”;
```

You can do it with this, but if you want to use this method with parameter than take a look at Regular Expressions topic at [Codeigniter User Guide - URI Routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

What function are you trying to call in the category controller?

Folder path : controllers/listtype/category.php
Then inside category.php you will have a function (e.g. view)

```
$route[‘alias/(:num)’] = “listtype/category/view/$1”;
```

You can then access the (:num) entered after alias in the function called view in the controller call categories.